# Canonical Header Links for PDF files in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, seo, httpd.conf, canonical-link

I'm attempting to setup Canonical links for a number of PDF files on my website.

I have urls with this path "**[https://www.test.com/wp-content/themes/theme_TEST/pdf/fr/test_04.pdf**"](https://www.test.com/wp-content/themes/theme_TEST/pdf/fr/test_04.pdf**%22) knowing that I can have several languages instead of "fr".

In httpd.conf, i set this configuration

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/home/wwwTEST/test.eu/www/test/wp-content/themes/theme_TEST/pdf/[^/]+">
    <FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
        Header set Link 'https://www.test.com/Catalog.html?pdf=<%{REQUEST_FILENAME}e>; rel="canonical"'
    </FilesMatch>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Restart Httpd Server Command

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

When i try to check the http status with https://httpstatus.io, i got this

[image]

How to correct to have the good name, and not null ?

Comment: In your case, it appears that the REQUEST_FILENAME environment variable is not being correctly populated, resulting in _null_ in the canonical link.  Would you try with **%{REQUEST_URI}** variable instead, which contains the requested URI, including the path and query string?

`<DirectoryMatch "^/home/wwwTEST/test.eu/www/test/wp-content/themes/theme_TEST/pdf/[^/]+">
    <FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
        Header set Link 'https://www.test.com/Catalog.html?pdf=%{REQUEST_URI}; rel="canonical"'
    </FilesMatch>
</DirectoryMatch>`